# Cannot open a Script Task, but only one specific SSIS package, any suggestions please?

Tags: vb.net, visual-studio, ssis, script-task, ssis-2005

For only one particular SSIS package (v. 2005) I am getting the following error when trying to open the script task...

> **TITLE: Microsoft Visual Studio**
>
> Cannot show the editor for this task.
>
> **ADDITIONAL INFORMATION:**
>
> The operation could not be completed. (Microsoft.VisualBasic.Vsa.DT)
>
> **BUTTONS:**
>
> OK

I need to get into this to be able to edit it, also I am in the process of upgrading it to 2014. Once upgraded I can get in, but there is no code, so assume the upgrade is not working as it=self cannot see the code within.

- I have tried other machines - same problem.
- I have tried other packages - they work fine - even in the same solution.
- I have tried a few resets found on the net/re-installs - same problem.

Clearly its something to do with this specific package only, but I am stumped.

I would expect to be able to open the Script task like any other, and be able to edit it. I would also expect the upgrade to work and contain the code.

Comment: Can you open the .cs file separately?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to read the Script Task code, open the package file *(.dtsx)* using a text editor *(Notepad++)*, and search for the Script Task code, copy the Script Task code and recreate the script and paste the code within the Script editor.

If you have a problem with Script Tasks in visual studio 2005, then copy the code to an external file, upgrade the package to 2014 then paste the code inside the Script Task *(since it will be empty after upgrade)*